# How do you Test a service where Maui.Storage.ISecureStorage is used

Tags: maui

I have to write an integration test and I have service like below

```
    public class MyService: IMyService
    {
        private readonly ISecureStorage secureStorageService;

        public MyService(ISecureStorage secureStorageService)
        {
            this.secureStorageService = secureStorageService;
        }
    }
```

How do I create an implementation of ISecureStorage in my test?

```
ISecureStorage mySecureStorage = new ???????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a test implementation for it or use a mock, since you don't want to test the real SecureStorage class (you can't, really, without a lot of platform specific fuzz).

**Option 1: Use the Moq library:**

```cs
using Moq;

public class MyTests
{
    // this conveniently takes care of the mock implementation for you
    private Mock<ISecureStorage> _secureStorageMock = new Mock<ISecureStorage>();

    [Test]
    public void Example()
    {
        //arrange
        var myService = new MyService(_secureStorageMock.object);

        //act
        myService.DoSomething();

        //assert
        Assert.IsTrue(myService.Whatever);
        // You can also check if a specific method has been called, like below
        _secureStorageMock.Verify(s => s.SetAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>());
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Create a stub implementation:**

```cs
public class FakeStorage : ISecureStorage
{
    //TODO: implement interface with stub methods that don't actually do anything useful 
}
```

Then use it in your test:

```cs
public class MyTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Example()
    {
        //arrange
        var myService = new MyService(new FakeStorage());

        //act
        myService.DoSomething();

        //assert
        Assert.IsTrue(myService.Whatever);
    }
}
```

These are just two ways to do it. More advanced scenarios could involve an inversion of control container. Also, I'm just assuming the use of NUnit here, but the same goes for xUnit, too.

I recommend approach no. 1. It's easier, more powerful and avoids writing a fake or stub implementation.

Comment: I am using xUnit , thanks for your answer  - I ended creating a Stub - but because is not a Unit Tests I didnt want to mock - I guess I have no option .  I really thought that this time round there were the interfaces . Interistily - how do you do DI with secure storage? how do you set it, myService<ISecureStorage,????> .. I thought they had fixed it . I use DryIOC

Comment: Well, SecureStorage is a platform specific implementation, depending on the current platform. There is no platform-agnostic version, because each platform handles it differently. On iOS, for example, the ISecureStorage implementation uses the keychain. You could always create a wrapper around it, if you need.

Comment: yes- makes sense - but when you want to test something and you have that interface injected in a service - testing becomes tricky. I am now more confident In what I am doing with it.